# first jquery click event not firing correctly in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a group of radio buttons in a div that is displayed after the user clicks a button.

```
<div id="quiz_take" class="media_layout quiz_panel hide">
    <div class="quiz_panel_layout">
        <p><b>Quiz4 Title</b></p>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="0-0" value="0" />
                    <label>wrong</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="0-1" value="1" />
                    <label>right</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="0-2" value="2" />
                    <label>wrong</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>Cras luctus ante a sem gravida rutrum?</div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="1-0" value="0" />
                    <label>right</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="1-1" value="1" />
                    <label>wrong</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="1-2" value="2" />
                    <label>wrong</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>Fusce vulputate porta sem, ut bibendum urna lacinia in?</div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="2-0" value="0" />
                    <label>wrong</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="2-1" value="1" />
                    <label>wrong</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ans">
                    <input type="radio" name="..." id="2-2" value="2" />
                    <label>right</label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="fit">
            <span id="submit_quiz" class="media_layout disabled-quiz-button button">Submit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in every browser, except for IE8 (the qa machine is an XP environment). It even works fine in IE7 oddly enough.

The event is handled by:

```
// can only submit if every radio group has selected
$('div.ans input:radio').live('click', function () {
    ...
});
```

This is the click event for a button above it that shows the quiz div:

```
// start quiz
$('#start_quiz').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('quiz-take-button')) {
        $('#quiz_ready').hide();
        $('#quiz_result').hide();
        $('div.ans input:radio').attr('checked', false);
        $('#quiz_take').show();
    }
});
```

The radio button event was originally a .click jquery event. But I've been trying many different methods to see troubleshoot. On the first click IE8 doesn't recognize it and the button is not selected, this is the case for any button. But each subsequent click does work. It's like one of the parent elements intercepts the first click. The css styling (padding and other spacing) is also not displaying correctly until after the first click event as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This ended up being an issue with hiding the #quiz_ready div that was directly above it, for whatever reason I have no clue. I altered the show() to be the fast animation show(10) and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating the depracted `.live()` method for `.on()` to see if it helps you get the problem solved.

```
$('div.ans').on('click','input:radio', function(){

})
```

Comment: This was one of my first attempts at debugging. But even this doesn't register until the second click. So I suppose it's an element above that div even?? I'm updating my question to show some of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want submit help?  how to validate when the user thinks they're done?

i had to guess at your above html code, so here is what I used below

## html

```
<div class="quiz-container">
  <div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q1"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1"/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="radio" name="q1"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1"/>
 </div>
  <div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q2"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2"/>
 </div>
 <div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q3"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q3"/>
  <input type="radio" name="q3"/>
 </div>
 <div class="submit">submit</div>
</div>
```

## javascript

so, for every quiz-container submit button, check every answer has a checked radio button. If not, give the question the "red" class, or whatever else you want to do to it.

```
$("div.quiz-container").on({
  "click":function(event){
    var quizContainer = $(this).closest(".quiz-container"),
        questions =$(".question",quizContainer) ,
        answers = $("input:radio:checked",quizContainer);
   if(questions.length !== answers.length){
      questions.not(answers.closest(".question")).addClass("red");
   }
}
},".submit",null);
```

Comment: note the html is not valid, I have a meeting to run and I didn't know you're exact needs.  hopefully this solution gives you an idea to use.  The above should not care what browser it's on ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug.  What version of jQuery are you using?  Here are a few workarounds that you can try.

I like using the 'change' event on input fields.

```
$('div.ans input:radio').live('change', function () {
```

Are the radio buttons loaded dynamically after the page has loaded?  If not, try removing the live.

```
$('div.ans input:radio').change(function () {
```

I’ve noticed issues with more complex CSS selectors.  Can you add a class to the radio button.

```
$('.myRadioButtonClass').live('change', function () {
```

Or maybe something like this.

```
$('div.ans').find('input').live('change', function () {
```